# how to access a particuar field in json array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I want to retrieve some feilds from the json data.
This is my json data:

```
[{"ipaddress":"10.132.32.212","id":"18"},    
 {"ipaddress":"10.132.32.213","id":"19"}]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div ng-app="lostsysApp" ng-controller="mainController">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in ipaddress | orderBy:'id'">
    {{ x.ipaddress + ', ' + x.id }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('lostsysApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {


$http({ method : "GET",
    url : "http://10.132.32.218:8080/DBtoWeb/services.jsp",
    Accept: "application/json"

    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myData=response.data;
      }, function myError(response) {
        //Second function handles error
        $scope.myData = "Something went wrong";
    
  });
});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```html
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData | orderBy:'id'">
```

Comment: in the above json data i need the values of ipaddress and id

Comment: Yep, and presuming response.data does contain the data you say it does (the JSON array), then the above code will work.

Comment: By the way assigning the string "Something went wrong" to myData is not a good idea, as you are asking the same scope field to contain two different types of data (an array or a string). You should assign the error string to some other field.

Comment: The code is correct, but something else is going on. Put a javascript breakpoint at the line $scope.myData=response.data; and inspect the response.data. BTW, it's unhelpful to say "the code will not work" without saying what fails and how. Is there an error? What happens exactly? Try to problem solve this a bit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A32WoOx7fygz15tIx66U?p=preview)

```
  <div ng-app="lostsysApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in myData | orderBy:'id'">
        {{ x.ipaddress + ', ' + x.id }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```